# can on_epoch_end just be defined as a regular function in fastai?

Tags: callback, fast-ai

why does it have to use callback, it may as well just do the job if you just define the function on_epoch_end as a regular function and place it at the end of the epoch in the train function in fastai right?

Answer (score 0):

The callback architecture is there to make fastai extendable without the need for modifying the code of the framework itself.

If you add a function call to the end of the `train` method, you will obviously change the code of fastai. Not only you will have to manage another version of the repository (the fork with your changes), but also this is bad from the architectural point of view. The fastai framework will become dependent on your code (tightly coupled with your code - you can google *low coupling*).

Of course, it is fine if you just want to try things out quickly. However, you should not do it if you want to build your project on top of fastai.